# Is that normal the loss is always near 0.55 after training?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I trained a DNN model and after only several batches, the loss decrease from 0.67 to 0.55 and it never drops again. The total count of my samples is 60 million and the batch size is 1000. So after several batches, the logloss seems steady and I am not sure whether the model has already been in a ideal status, or just fall into a local min area. 
The loss is calculated by the tf.losses.log_loss.
Thanks.

Comment: Your learning rate should not be constant, it should be decaying, you can try adam optimizer if you are not using it. To identify when to stop training or what is the best combination of hyper parameters(learning rate, number of epochs for which model need to be trained,  etc.), you can compare performance parameters(depends on task) on your validation dataset for different checkpoints corresponding to different hyper-parameters.

Comment: Well, I am using adam optimizer and what confused me most is that my model has no classify ability since its auc is always 0.5. The initial learning rate is 0.01

Comment: to verify your training process, you can train it on small data like 10-20 images of 2 class, and just try to overfit it and see whether it is able to classify then.